# Is it possible to install Firefox addons otherwise than using the browser?

Tags: firefox, browser-addons, firefox-extensions

Is it possible to install Firefox addons just **by copying some files** - not having to start the browser?

I'd want to install Firefox with a lot of extensions on other devices, but doing it manually would be just painful.

Comment: You should add why this would be useful or the reason using FF would be a problem.

Comment: @user3169 edited

Answer (score 1):

Depends. If you have installed it before, and you copy the profile folder with the plugins and settings already there, it will correctly be copied.

But if you want to install a new plugin, it also has to be registered. For that, you do need firefox.

Unless of course you know how to manually register the plugin inside firefox, but using firefox is usually much easier. Often you can simply open the plugin installer with firefox.

Comment: Is this profile folder "cross-platform", as in, will copying the folder from Ubuntu to Windows work?

Comment: I don't know. Give it a try and see what happens. I would suspect that it is, but again, I don't know. I do know that if you use FireFox's account and sync, it will also sync plugins and automatically installs them. That is far likely to also be cross-platform.

Comment: I would not recommend to copy a firefox-profile-folder from Ubuntu to Windows. I never tried that, but if I compare the settings in about:config it seems slightly different.